# Why my Unity game in Android freezes when calling LoadScene?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, freeze

The game freezes permanently when I try to load the next scene but when I load it with "Additive" mode it's loaded fine (using *SceneManager.LoadScene("NextScene", LoadSceneMode.Additive)*).
In editor everything works even with mode "Single", the problem only appears with Android.
I don't want to use the "Additive" mode because it loads the content of the new scene above the old one.
I try:

- using "adb logcat" to see if any exception occurs but there are no exceptions.
- load an empty scene as a new scene but the problem still appears.
- load using *SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("NextScene")* but the problem still appear.
- load with "Additive" mode and after the next scene is loaded I try to Unload the old scene using *SceneManager.UnloadScene("OldScene")* but it freezes again.

So the problem appears when Unity try to unload the old scene.
(I use Unity 2018.4.10f1 LTS).
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to build the game with PC and I face the same problem.
I see what in the output_log.txt file in "C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/.../My game name/Crashes" and the first readable messages after the crash are like this:
"**ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: 'Attempt to access invalid address.' (Address: 00007FFEF20E5212)**"
without any other errors or exceptions by my game,
so I try to test the game with an updated version of Unity (2018.4.10f1 --> 2018.4.20f1),

Abracadabra everything works fine with the new version!!
and the problem doesn't appear anymore!!
I think it was a memory management problem in Unity 2018.4.10f1 but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the objects from the last scene
In for loop to see what object response for the error

Comment: Actually I try it but no change.